# Is it safe to call observe method of a ResizeObserver multiple times on an element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webapi

I have a situation in react, where I need to observer the size of each child element of a react component. I have created a new ResizeObserver.

```
ro = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((i) => {
    console.log(i.contentRect.height);
    // some action on resize
  });
});
```

And to observer all children I ran a loop in `componentDidMount`

```
Array.prototype.map.call(this.elementRef.current.children, (item) => {
        this.ro.observe(item);
      });
```

I also added code to unobserve in `componentDidUnmount`

```
Array.prototype.map.call(this.elementRef.current.children, (item) => {
            this.ro.unobserve(item);
          });
```

Now, I have a scenario that children can increase dynamically without triggering remount. So I am adding `componentDidMount` code to `componentDidUpdate`. I am wondering if that is safe or will I have to identify which children currently not being observed and then only run observe on new children. If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to call `observe` multiple times on the same element as noted in the [specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer/#dom-resizeobserver-observe).

Consider observing the parent container instead of the children if the children sizing affect the parent.